# Building the decoder of an autoencoder with same dimensions or parameters as the encoder?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I build an variational autoencoder from the example given on Keras and changed the layers. The resulting decoder has much more parameters than the encoder. For the decoder I mirrored the conv-Layers with conv_transpose-Layers that have the same parameters as the encoder conv-Layers.

So my question is if I want to build an decoder do I mirror the dimensions of the encoder or do I mirror the encoder conv-Layers with conv_transpose-Layers in the decoder that have the same parameters as the conv-Layers?

The model summary:
Encoder:

`````
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 64, 64, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 32, 32, 32)   1568        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)         (None, 32, 32, 32)   0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 32, 32, 32)   128         activation[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 16, 16, 32)   16416       batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 16, 16, 32)   0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 16, 16, 32)   128         activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 16, 16, 32)   9248        batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 16, 16, 32)   0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 16, 16, 32)   128         activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 8, 8, 64)     32832       batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, 8, 8, 64)     0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 8, 8, 64)     256         activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 8, 8, 64)     36928       batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, 8, 8, 64)     0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 8, 8, 64)     256         activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 8, 8, 64)     36928       batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, 8, 8, 64)     0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 8, 8, 64)     256         activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 8, 8, 32)     18464       batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, 8, 8, 32)     0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 8, 8, 32)     128         activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 1, 1, 512)    1049088     batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)       (None, 1, 1, 512)    0           conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 1, 1, 512)    2048        activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 512)          0           batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_mean (Dense)                  (None, 512)          262656      flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_log_var (Dense)               (None, 512)          262656      flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sampling (Sampling)             (None, 512)          0           z_mean[0][0]                     
                                                                 z_log_var[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,730,112
Trainable params: 1,728,448
Non-trainable params: 1,664
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Decoder:

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Model: "decoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 512)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 1, 1, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 8, 8, 512)         16777728  
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (Batch (None, 8, 8, 512)         2048      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 8, 8, 32)          147488    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (Batch (None, 8, 8, 32)          128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 8, 8, 64)          18496     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (Batc (None, 8, 8, 64)          256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, 8, 8, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (Batc (None, 8, 8, 64)          256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 16, 16, 64)        65600     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DTr (None, 16, 16, 32)        18464     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (Batc (None, 16, 16, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_6 (Conv2DTr (None, 32, 32, 32)        16416     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (Batc (None, 32, 32, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_7 (Conv2DTr (None, 64, 64, 32)        16416     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (Batc (None, 64, 64, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_8 (Conv2DTr (None, 64, 64, 3)         867       
=================================================================
Total params: 17,101,731
Trainable params: 17,100,067
Non-trainable params: 1,664
_________________________________________________________________
````
`````

Comment: It is not clear for me what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is the decoder of my variational autoencoder build correctly? (Mirroring the conv-Layers with conv_transpose-Layers that have the same parameters) Or should I aim to mirror the dimensions of my encoder. For example build the first conv_transpose-Layer so that I get a dimenision of (1, 1, 512) instead of (8, 8, 512).